# Closing the spacing for \sum_{\substack{}}\cdots\sum_{\substack{}}

Tags: spacing, gap

Here is the code I have that produces the output below. I wanted to learn if there is a way to close the gap around '\cdots'. And similarly between '=' and '\sum' on left, 'sum' and '\mathbb{P}' on right.

```
\sum_{\substack{x_T\in
    \mb{S}_T\\\nu_T\in\mb{P}^N(\mb{S}_T)}} \cdots
\sum_{\substack{x_1\in
    \mb{S}_1\\\nu_1\in\mb{P}^N(\mb{S}_1)}}
```

[image: Related Latex output]

Note: If the solution is complicated, no need to spend time as this document is not required to be esthetic. I only want to learn. Also, not sure about the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that wide spacing because of the width of the expressions in your `\substack` expression. Arguably that's not really what you want.

The simplest route to what you want is to use `\!` to insert negative thin spaces to tighten things up (I found three `\!` on either side of the `\cdots` looked ok. It's possible to make a wrapper around `\substack` that will cause LaTeX to ignore its width for spacing purpose, but that  brings things too close together so I would lean against that option because you'll almost certainly end up with the subscripts bumping up against each other. Here's what I did and its results:

```
\newcommand{\Substack}[1]{\hbox to 0pt{\hss $\substack{ #1}$\hss}}

\[
  = \sum_{\Substack{x_T\in \mb{S}_T\\\nu_T\in\mb{P}^N(\mb{S}_T)}} \cdots
    \sum_{\Substack{x_1\in \mb{S}_1\\\nu_1\in\mb{P}^N(\mb{S}_1)}}
\]
```

[image: Appearance of above LaTeX output with overlapping subscripts]

Comment: Thank you, \! indeed tighten a bit. Is it straightforward to do the wrapper around \substack? I just wanted to try.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a wrapper code and its result

Comment: Adding \hspace{0.6em} before and after \cdots actually worked really well, thanks.